# How to disable right-button selection on List View Item (ListViewItem)?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

I want to prevent the ability to deselect a list view item if it is already selected. Therefore how do I prevent right mouse click ability to deselect an item?

I have prevented the ability to deselect via swiping by using `IsSwipeEnabled="False"` on the List View. I didn't require swipe ability on the list view.

I'm happy to completely prevent right mouse click on the list view items if needed.

Comment: I removed your "Silverlight" tag on the question, as that is a different flavor of xaml than Windows Runtime xaml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am reading your question correctly, it sounds like you want the ability for the user to select items, but to not be able to de-select. If that is the case, it seems like a strange requirement - it goes against normal UI convention and does something that the user is not expecting.

Having said that, you can do so by handling the [SelectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.selectionchangedeventargs.aspx) event in the `ListView`.

When the event is triggered, it gives you a list of removed (de-selected) items. You then just need to add those items back into the ListView's selected items list:

```
private void itemListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in e.RemovedItems)
    {
        itemListView.SelectedItems.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Note that if you use the above code, you do not have to handle any swipe or mouse events.

---

**Edit** - Per OP's comment, the requirement is slightly different than what I thought:

> I want the selected item to deselect if a different item is selected. however what I dont want is an already selected item to be (manually) deselected

Assuming that you have a single select `ListView`, you can still use the `SelectionChanged` event and the `SelectionChangedEventArgs` to do what you are asking for:

```
private void itemListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RemovedItems.Count > 0 && e.AddedItems.Count == 0)
    {
        var removed = e.RemovedItems[0];
        itemListView.SelectedItem = removed;
    }
}
```

Comment: you miss an `if(e.AddedItems.Count==0)` or something like that

Comment: oh sry my mistake i misunderstood the question. I thought he only want to so if the user deselect all Items. so +1 :)

Comment: thanks chue. I know it sounds strange. imagine Outlook.com where there a list of folder names down the left side of the page. those are my listview items. I always want content to display on the right depending on which folder is selected on the left - therefore the ability to deselect a selected item is not desirable. the user should only be able to change which one is selected, one and only one item should always be selected. I will try your code when I get chance and give you a green tick if it does the job

Comment: am I right in thinking this isnt going to work for my purposes? i.e. I want the selected item to deselect if a different item is selected. however what I dont want is an already selected item to be deselected. with the above code, when I select a different item, isnt there then going to be 2 selected items?

Comment: @DaveHaigh - yes you are correct. The old code does not allow an item to ever be de-selected. (Think Tic-Tac-Toe). See if my new code (under the edit) resolves your issue.

Comment: I had to Google Tic-Tac-Toe and see that what you really meant was Noughts and crosses (I'm English) :) Awesome, new code does exactly what I need. Thanks chue

Answer (score 1):

I have found a simple solution on the following [forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/6c0301f5-8eab-4222-be8e-075b13cf25bc/how-to-disable-the-right-click-selection-for-listview?forum=winappswithcsharp).

You simply add a RightTapped event to the ListView DataTemplate content.

```
<ListView>
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
         <ContentPresenter RightTapped="daves_RightTapped" />
       </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

And then in the code behind:

```
private void daves_RightTapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

This works fine on an outlook style ListView.